# Dynamically events jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few dynamidally added elements (with `class="myClass`). I want to add `mouseenter` listener. My code is:

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter','.myClass',function(){
    console.log("in")
});
```

It works but there are logs all the time when cursor is on this element. How it is possible to modify it to get result like there is only one event (when user's cursor is entered in element and then is nothing when he is in)?

Comment: `$('.myClass').mouseenter(function(){ console.log('in') });`

Comment: @Kinduser that completely defeats the point of the delegated handler.

Comment: try `.one()` it runs only once

Comment: OP, it's most likely due to the child elements in the `.myClass` element. Could you add your HTML to the question.

Comment: @guradio it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

At least the JS part you gave is working properly.

```js
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter','.myClass',function(){
    console.log("in")
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```